# unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable

Tags: permissions

today i logged in to find i can't even cd into /var/ directory. I've checked that ownership and it's correct.

/var/www/ is inaccessible from the web browser. it says 403 forbidden.

error log shows

```
/var/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
```

Comment: Please post more details, e.g. the output of `ls -ld /var /var/www`.

Comment: You're superuser, you see `var`, but you can't `cd` into it?  Is it mounted on a separate drive?  Perhaps you have a failed disk?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
chmod 501 /var
```

I have had the same issue with my home dir

```
Permission denied: /var/www/username/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
```

All my sites are in the `/var/www/username/www`
So the solution was

```
chmod 501 /var/www/username
```